# Is there a proper way to handle DOM ready event with require.js? (no, domReady plugin doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, requirejs

I've read a lot of Stack Exchange questions on that matter (a couple of dozens, I think); unfortunately, they are either primitive and cover slightly different issues, or are badly formatted and unanswered, or answered incorrectly (though some are accepted). I will try to keep my examples as small as possible to illustrate the problem.

## A page with jQuery, a large image and DOM ready event handler

Let's take a simplest example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
        var start = Date.now();
        function log(s) { console.log((Date.now()-start), s); }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {log('Real DOMContentLoaded');});
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        log('jQuery loaded');
        $(function() { log('jQuery DOM ready'); });
        $(window).load(function() { log('jQuery document loaded'); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png">
</body>
```

The code works as expected, jQuery's DOM ready event fires early:

```
288 "jQuery loaded"
307 "jQuery DOM ready"
314 "Real DOMContentLoaded"
1376 "jQuery document loaded"
```

## The same with require.js

Now let's use require.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
        var start = Date.now();
        function log(s) { console.log((Date.now()-start), s); }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {log('Real DOMContentLoaded');});
    </script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"
            }
        });
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            log('jQuery loaded');
            $(function() { log('jQuery DOM ready'); });
            $(window).load(function() { log('jQuery document loaded'); });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png">
</body>
```

Suddenly, jQuery's DOM ready event doesn't fire until the document is fully loaded:

```
297 "Real DOMContentLoaded"
607 "jQuery loaded"
1255 "jQuery DOM ready"
1258 "jQuery document loaded"
```

Apparently, jQuery misses the browser's DOMContentLoaded event and thus falls back to window.onload to run its own ready event.

## The same with require.js domReady plugin

Now let's add require.js'es own domReady plugin to the blend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
        var start = Date.now();
        function log(s) { console.log((Date.now()-start), s); }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {log('Real DOMContentLoaded');});
    </script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min",
                domReady: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady/2.0.1/domReady"
            }
        });
        require(["domReady"], function(domReady) {
            log('domReady loaded');
            domReady(function() { log('domReady DOM ready'); });
        });
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            log('jQuery loaded');
            $(function() { log('jQuery DOM ready'); });
            $(window).load(function() { log('jQuery document loaded'); });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png">
</body>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work any different from jQuery's ready event:

```
341 "Real DOMContentLoaded"
582 "jQuery loaded"
648 "domReady loaded"
1284 "jQuery DOM ready"
1289 "jQuery document loaded"
1299 "domReady DOM ready"
```

## Question

Is there a proper, beautiful, cross-browser way to attach a DOM ready handler with require.js and jQuery without custom hacks and reinventing the wheel? And what's the point of having require-domReady plugin at all, if it doesn't really work?

Comment: jquery ends up being loaded asynchronously rather than synchronously, resulting in it loading after DOMContentLoaded has already happened, therefore binding to it is useless. That's why it goes to the fallback.

Comment: @Kevin, right, that's what I was trying to say. jQuery loads lately and doesn't get the original DOMContentLoaded browser event and thus doesn't fire its own ready event (until window.onload is fired by the browser, which jQuery uses as a fallback mechanism). Too bad it doesn't try to detect if the DOM is already ready at the moment it loads. (It could be impossible, though.)

Comment: That was my next question, is it possible to detect if the dom is already ready.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible in a cross-browser way.

Comment: Test the crossbrowser support of document.readystate

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm tearing my hair out that this seemingly simple problem doesn't seem to have a reasonable solution anywhere

Comment: @calumbrodie, I added my own solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I will not mark this as "accepted" since I'm not proud of the solution, but here's what I ended up with, for the record (someone was asking in the comments). I've coded my solution as the `domReadyEx` function that I add to jQuery to make it readily available everywhere jQuery is used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
        var start = Date.now();
        function log(s) { console.log((Date.now()-start), s); }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {log('Real DOMContentLoaded');});
    </script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"
            }
        });
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            log('jQuery loaded');
            $.domReadyEx = function(handler) {
                // Poor jQuery can't figure it itself if loaded asynchronously and falls back to window.onload which is undesirably late.
                if (document.readyState == 'interactive' || document.readyState == 'complete') {
                    handler();
                } else {
                    $(document).ready(handler);
                }
            }
            $(function() { log('jQuery DOM ready'); });
            $(window).load(function() { log('jQuery document loaded'); });
            $.domReadyEx(function() { log('jQuery.domReadyEx'); });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png">
</body>
```

The output:

```
417 "Real DOMContentLoaded"
516 "jQuery loaded"
517 "jQuery.domReadyEx"
1123 "jQuery DOM ready"
1128 "jQuery document loaded"
```

I'm pretty sure it's not fully cross-browser, but I don't care about the code working slower in older browsers or IE.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. The solution is the `domReadyEx` plugin, right? It would be good to highlight this fact so that people don't just scratch their heads. I've read your question a while back and just came back to it now to read the answer and it took me a while to figure out where the solution was.

Comment: @Louis, no, it's not like that. There is no domReadyEx plugin (not that I'm aware of, at least). The entire solution is included in the answer, and it doesn't use any new plugins. domReadyEx is a simple custom function that I wrote.

Comment: @IlyaSemenov Yeah, I understand that `domReadyEx` is your code. The way I see it though (and this seems to be consistent with jQuery's [doc](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)) if you add a function to jQuery, you've in effect created a plugin. What I'm saying is that people have to search for `domReadyEx` in your code to realize that it is the solution. I'll edit your answer with what I"m thinking and you can roll-back if that's not acceptable to you.